# AWS cloudwatch alarm without aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We know AWS cloudwatch alarms use aggregation(Min,Max,Sum,Average) of data points in given evaluation period to trigger alarm. We have monitoring requirement where we want to trigger alarm if ALL(not aggregation) data point value in evaluation period is greater than threshold value. This is to avoid false alarm in case of spike followed by insufficient data. For example, in 5 mins period if we have 2 mins spike then we don't want alarm. If value is constantly above threshold for 5 mins then we want alarm. One option could be creating custom alarm. I want to know can this be done without customization or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use 1-minute granularity instead of 5-minute granularity.

If 5 consecutive periods (of 1-minute each) is above your threshold, then trigger the alarm.

Comment: How I can figure out point value stayed above threshold for 5 mins in case I have few spikes less than a min? AWS only provides aggregate functions. In case of spike aggregate result can result above threshold even though only one spike is very high.

Comment: Use a "Period" of 60 seconds (which is 1 minute) and trigger the alarm when 5 consecutive periods are >= your threshold. The alarm will only trigger if the metric was above the threshold for the entire 5 minutes.